# try / catch vs then() / catch() for [err, result] = await promise

Tags: node.js, async-await, try-catch

This might be a duplicate, but I haven't found an answer yet.

I want expression `let result = await promise;` to return result in Node.js style `[err, result]`.

There are two solutions. Since I am not too familiar with Node.js/then()/catch()/async/await, I would like to know the advantages/disadvantages of each approach.

First (https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-to-js):

I found it here: https://blog.grossman.io/how-to-write-async-await-without-try-catch-blocks-in-javascript

```
function to(promise) {
   return promise.then(data => {
      return [null, data];
   })
   .catch(err => [err]);
}
```

Second:

```
async function to2(promise) {
  try {
    return [null, await promise];
  } catch (e) {
    return [e];
  }
}
```

Both are called the same way: `let [err, user] = await to/to2(User.create(...));`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2020:**

This is how I am working now. I am using helper function for this, instead of a library.

```
//helpers.js

export function until(promiseOrPromiseList) {
  if (!promiseOrPromiseList) {
    console.error("no promise passed.",promiseOrPromiseList);
    return Promise.reject(["Unknown Error"]);
  }
  //array of promises
  if (Array.isArray(promiseOrPromiseList)) {
    return Promise.all(promiseOrPromiseList)
      .then((data) => {
        return [null, data];
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return [err, promiseOrPromiseList.map((p) => undefined)];
      });
  }
  //single promise call
  return promiseOrPromiseList
    .then((data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      return [null, data];
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // console.log(err)
      return [err];
    });
}
```

My usage would be like -

```
import {until} from "../helpers.js";

async function sendUserDetails() {
    const [err, user] = await until(getUserFromDb(userId));
    if (err) {
      errorLog.error(err);
      return res.json({success:false,msg:"An Error occured"})
    }
    res.json({success:true,user:user})
   }
```

So, you simply wrap your function that returns promise inside `until` and assign it to tuple(array of two items here) to get `err` and `result` as the case may be.

**Old Answer:**

I think you donot need to use any of the libraries to write readable, synchronous looking async code.
I have been using async-await without try/catch blocks, the following way -

```
//write a promise
function getUserFromDb(userId){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       if(userId == undefined){
          return reject('no userId specified');//return to stop proceeding further.
       }
       UserModel.findById(userId,function(err,user){
          if(err) return reject('error while fetching user details.')
          resolve(user);
    });
}
//-------------------

//usage
//remember to use async keyword before function declaration
//... 

let user = await getUserFromDb(userId).catch(err=>console.log(err));

//user will be undefined, if the promise was rejected.
if(!user){
   console.log('error while getting the details');
}
//...
```

or, if you want to use errors specifically,

```
//usage
let user,userErr;
user = await getUserFromDb(userId).catch(err=>userErr = err);
if(!user){
console.log(userErr);
}
```

with one extra line, you can avoid using an external library and wrapping your code in an unnecessary function.

But if you have to go with one of your snippets, then the first one is much better since try/catch blocks do slow down performance.

Comment: Yes, but having to append `.catch(err=>userErr = err)` is what I am trying to get rid of

Comment: Well, I never felt it to be a problem and I haven't found a shorter version for me. Would love to know. Considering the nesting with promises and wrapping functions with libraries, it actually feels good to go with native features of the language, at such a short cost.
 But if you get comfortable with using a micro library and enjoy a sweet looking syntax, then it is well and good.